# SQL Error SQL DB function failed with error number 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I have prblem with sql when i try to check if table extist.

Am making component for joomla and when make install.sql i have sql syntax error.

check this and tell me what i do wrong:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_item`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_categories`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_type`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_price_type`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_agnts`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_companies`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_agnts`;

CREATE  TABLE `#__ik_property_item` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `category_id` INT NULL ,
  `property_type_id` INT NULL ,
  `price_type_id` INT NULL ,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `agent_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `street` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `status` INT NULL ,
  `featured` INT NULL ,
  `yt_video` TEXT NULL ,
  `map_lattitude` INT NULL ,
  `map_longitude` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `beds` INT NULL ,
  `baths` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `garage` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `flat_size` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `kitchens` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `year_build` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `floor` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `price` INT NULL ,
  `image_1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `image_2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `image_3` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `image_4` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `image_5` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `meta_title` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `meta_description` TEXT NULL ,
  `intro_text` TEXT NULL ,
  `full_text` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

CREATE  TABLE `#__ik_property_categories` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

CREATE  TABLE `#__ik_property_type` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

CREATE  TABLE `#__ik_property_price_type` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

CREATE  TABLE `#__ik_property_agnts` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `website` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `company` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

CREATE  TABLE `#__ik_property_companies` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `logo` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `website` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `street` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `fax` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `intro_text` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `full_text` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `image_1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `image_2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `image_3` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

When i remove

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_item`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_categories`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_type`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_price_type`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_agnts`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_companies`;
DROP TABLE IF EXIST `#__ik_property_agnts`;
```

All is success executed and when i call uninstall.sql code inside is like above all work good. But i need to check on installation if that tables exist if exist i must delete and save new.

Thanks

Comment: The correct syntax is [`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html), note `EXISTS` instead of `EXIST`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is related to a minor syntactic typo

Comment: OMG What a rookie mistake i do... Cant beleve am idiot... thanks @michael